# cannot read the text file properly anymore

Tags: c++, bash, terminal, output

Alright so basically this is my program that reads a text file and place it inside of an array, in the end I printed out everything in that array. The program run fine and yielded the correct result few days. However, it just stopped working today. For instance the text file is

```
88
687
472
671
```

But upon the completion of the program the output is 0 1073741824 0 1073741824.  I dont know what is going on and the only time I made some change to the bash was ulimit -s unlimited. Any idea?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream file(argv[1]);
    int placeholder;
    int size = pow(2,atoi(argv[2]));
    int array[size];
    int index = 0;
    while (file >> placeholder)
    {
        array[index]=placeholder;
        index++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout<<array[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's not opening the file successfully.  You attempt to read from the stream without checking that it's valid first -- maybe it's not reading anything at all, and you're printing the contents of uninitialized data.

Comment: You also do not check or care if there are no arguments passed. I mean what would the value of size be if argc is less than 3. And I would avoid VLAs.

Comment: @drescherjm for the simplicity of the implementation  I just assume there are always two argument, one being the file name and the second one being n

Comment: @xiaocheng `int array[size];` Use a `std::vector<int>` instead, to have portable c++ code please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your text-file is readable by the program? If the input file does not exist, the program will still try to print `argv[2]**2` entries from `array` which does not contain any elements! The program ends up dumping garbage values.

I am also not sure why you do the `pow` call - why not get the number of elements from `argv[2]`?

Also, you use some c functions (`atoi`) when you could use C++ `stringstream` to do the conversion.

When I run your code with the input you provide, like this: `./a.out file.txt 2`, it prints the 4 numbers as expected. When I do this instead: `./a.out does_not_exist.txt 2`, it prints 4 garbage values and dumps them to the screen.